# Security warning CA2151 in C++/CLI Project while consuming C struct inside reference type

Tags: c++, security, winapi, c++-cli, static-analysis

In the scenario we have two projects, Win32 GUI (App) which uses C code and second project (Component) is a Dynamic Library with Command Language Runtime Support Switch /CLR enabled. App has “.h” file declaring typical C-style typedef struct (to hold data). This struct is when used inside Component project, static code analysis throws the security warning CA2151: Fields with critical types should be security critical

Here is the code snippet, Header file **Data.h** in GUI App (Win32 project) has this structure declaration

```
#pragma once

typedef struct tagDATA
{
    double intersectionPointX;
    double intersectionPointY;
    double intersectionPointZ;
    double endPointX;
    double endPointY;
    double endPointZ;
} DATA;
```

The code file (.CPP) in C++/CLI project ComponentDll.cpp has this code

```
using namespace System::Security;

#include "../MyWin32App/Data.h"
ref class ComponentAdapter
{
    NOZZLEDATA *data; //CA2151 Fields with critical types should be security critical.

    void foo()
    {
        double x = 2.0;
        data->endPointX = x;
    }
};
```

Query is twofold, first what kind of security threat is posed to the application if this issue is not fixed, second how to cope with this warning effectively or best practices to address this problem?

Comment: 80% of the secret of using a static code analyzer correctly is to select a subset of all of the checks it can perform.  Choosing the ones that represent real issues and are actionable.  If you have no idea how to get that started then do pick one of the pre-installed rule sets to kick it off.  You want "Microsoft Mixed (C++/CLR) Recommended Rules".  Which has CA2151 turned off, as it should be.

Comment: @Hans, the security ruleset I am using is customized by other team (security team). Would not have faced this problem if I was using the default ruleset :) After lot of reading on MSDN I came across the recommendation that the warning should not be suppressed [https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn621098.aspx]. I just wanted to understand that is it false positive? or the way we are using our legacy code in newer C++/CLI component is not right? I read somewhere in MSDN that the Security Level of C++/CLI is "1" and that of C# project is "2"

Comment: Why are you talking to strangers on the Internet??  Talk to your security team.  If they don't want to listen then tell them that somebody told you that enabling CA2151 in mixed-mode code that requires full trust to run is dead wrong.  If that does not convince them then they can click the Ask Question button here.

Comment: @Hans, make sense, so simply speaking the warning CA2151 should be turned off for mixed mode code as it requires full trust level to execute. Thanks for your help there.